# Не работает Javascript при помещении кода,как в html-файл, так и в .js

Tags: javascript, css3

[[image: Скрин экрана]

Я открыла вкладку "Консоль", как вы и сказали.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Покажите весь код html, или откройте консоль(F12, вкладка консоль), там может быть ошибка

Comment: что конкретно не работает? какие ошибки? что этот код должен делать и что делает в вашем случае?

Comment: Начнем с того, что это не чистый js. Используется библиотека jquery, и, следовательно, ее нужно подключить. Также весь код нужно обернуть в $( document ).ready() http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Это скрин экрана с открытой консолью

Comment: нет в консоли ошибок. вам уже сказали - покажите весь код полностью, с HTML. без него просто невозможно помочь.